# Proving that there is no function that satisfies the conditions

Tags: calculus, limits

Prove that there can't be a function $g$ such that $g(x) \neq 0$ and $\lim_{x\to a}(\frac{1}{g(x)}+g(x)) = 0$

I tried to prove this by contradiction.
I assumed that such function exists, and from the definition of limit there exists a $\delta > 0$ so that for all $0<|x-a|<\delta$ :
$|\frac{1}{g(x)}+g(x) - 0| = |\frac{1+g^2(x)}{g(x)}| < ... < \epsilon$
But I couldn't get to a contradiction.
Can I get a lead?

Comment: You would need $\lim_{x\to a}(g(x))^2=-1$, which is not possible.

Comment: @AndrewChin Indeed, I realized that. I'm just having trouble proving it with $\epsilon$ and $\delta$

Comment: For any nonzero $a$, $|a+ \frac{1}{a}|\ge 2$.  Show for $a>0$,  by removing abs. value, multiplying both sides by $a$ and completing to a square. Use symmetry for negative $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon = 2$, and for any $\delta > 0$,  $\forall c \in  (a - \delta, a + \delta)$, either $f(c) > 0$ or $f(c) < 0 \implies \dfrac{1}{f(c)} + f(c) \ge 2$ or $\dfrac{1}{f(c)} + f(c) \le -2\implies \left|\dfrac{1}{f(c)} + f(c)-0\right| = \left|\dfrac{1}{f(c)} + f(c)\right|\ge 2= \epsilon$. This shows the limit cannot be $0$, and this means $g(x)$ can't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$ \bigg(\frac{1}{g(x)}+g(x)\bigg)^2=\frac{1}{g^2(x)}+g^2(x)+2\ge2 $$
and hence if
$$ \lim_{x\to a}(\frac{1}{g(x)}+g(x)) = 0$$
we would have
$$ 0\ge2$$
which is absurd.